# Mac Book Pro SSD

Tags: mac, ssd, macbook-pro

I have a Mac Book Pro (I7 and 8 Gig Ram). I'm a developer - do a fair amount of .net via VMware but lots of Ruby and NodeJs on the Mac.

I'm looking to extract some more performance and i think a SSD might be a good option. So I have 2 questions,

1. Can I straight up replace the drive thats in there with a SSD or
   will this cause me problems? I have files on there as well as apps.
2. What are my options in terms of available hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Your options depend on your model of Mac Book Pro

One all systems you can replace the HDD with a regular SSD.
You will either have to reinstall your OS and applications or do something with images.

If you model has a CDROM bay you can replace that with a bay for a 2½ drive. That gives you two options:

1. Put the new SSD in it and use it. Easiest, but not the fastest solution.
2. Put the new SSD in place of the old HDD and put the old drive in the new tray. Put all applications which require speed on the fast SSD, move non critical things (E.g, movies, music, backups of the VMs) to the HDD.

There are two things to check though:

- Some old Macs did not work with SATA-2 speeds. This may require a jumper to be set on the SSD.
- TRIM is not on by default on all drives. With an older OS this meant changing some values in drivers. I think they changed that is the newer OS X versions.

Regardless, it does not hurt to google on these item and check precisely which OS and MAc Book Pro version you have.

Answer (score 1):

The MacBook Pro uses standard SATA connectors so you can just swap the drives. You will need to either re-install or clone the existing drive.

Have a look a [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63198/new-macbook-pro-2012-operating-system-onto-new-ssd) on Ask Different (the Apple section of StackExchange) for full details.